# how to reuse previous variable value after closing program

Tags: java

```
public class UseVariableValueAgain{

    public static void main(String args[]){
        int x=6;

        int y=7;
        int LastValue=0;// for first time
        LastValue=x+y+LastValue;

        System.out.println("result"+LastValue);
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        int x1=scan.nextInt();
        int y1=scan.nextInt();
        int LastValue1=0;
        LastValue1=x1+y1+LastValue1;//for first time 

        System.out.println("REsult using Scanner="+LastValue1);


    }

}
Ressult=13
5
6
Result using Scanner=11
```

> when i execute this program i got 13 output by default and by using scanner
>       i enter 5,6 and output is 11 , Now I want to  use (13,11)values for next 
>       time when i re-execute the program. but it give same result

Comment: You'll need to store the value somewhere then; like a file or a database.

Comment: you'll need some persistence storage to store previous values

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a file and write to a file in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2885173/how-to-create-a-file-and-write-to-a-file-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

Your options in order of easiness:

1) Next time when you invoke the program, pass the values at the command line.
`java UseVariableValueAgain 13 11`. You will have access to these values via `args[]` array now. Keep in mind you will have to parse this to integer as `args` is a String array.

2) Write these values to a file. (eg using BufferedWriter) and read it in the program using `Scanner` or `BufferedReader`;

3) Write the value to a database table. Read the values from the table in your program.

In all these options, you will have to check if this is a re-run by employing appropriate if-else conditions to check if the value needs to be read from user input or if it needs to be determined.
If you are learning Java, I recommend trying all three options in that sequence.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write the previous value in a persistent storage(like `file`).